# Практика на C# в примерах?

Tags: c#

При изучении языка большое внимание уделяется примерам, которые не несут практического применения. Для начала обучения — это несомненно нужно. После того, как узнаёшь всё больше и больше о языке, появляется очевидное желание двигаться дальше и переходить к практике. И очевидный ход — это найти практику в какой-нибудь конторке за копейки, где тебя натаскают. Идеальный вариант! Но бывает, что устроиться за копейки пока не представляется возможным и нужно натаскаться так, чтобы устроиться уже на работу с окладом! А практику найти не так просто. И эта тема должна помочь тем, кто не имеет возможности практиковаться на реальной работе.

**Предлагаю писать сюда реальные примеры первых заданий, которые были получены при такой практике в компании.** 
 Объяснять решение не требуется. Просто ТЗ и возможно, что должно в итоги получиться. Ошибки, подсказки, с которыми авторы примера столкнулись. Для того чтобы те, кто попробует выполнить его для практики, стремились к правильному результату.

 Информация была бы очень полезна как мне, так и тем, кто тоже ищет что-либо подобное.

 **Прошу писать только по теме.**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75899/discussion-on-question-by-j-atisto---c--).

Comment: @j.Atisto это *в вашей компетенции*. онтопик можно изменить через обсуждение на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Два консольных приложения.

Первое. На вход идёт параметр или параметры в виде адресов:
- google.com
- mail.com
На выходе создается структурированное дерево каталогов с файлами.
Файлы представляют сериализованные объекты .css-файлов. Файлы брать из исходного кода страниц путём парсинга. Собирать файлы как по ссылкам, так и по самим тегам

```
<style type="text/css">
   h1 { 
    font-size: 120%; 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: #333366;
   }
  </style>
```

Парсинг осуществлять регулярными выражениями([классный online инструмент](https://regexr.com/) для работы с регулярками). Сериализацию использовать [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial).

Второе приложение висит в ожидании новых файлов в подкаталогах, по их появлению начинает обработку. Обработка заключается в десериализации и сохранение в БД.
Для работы с БД написать несколько основных функций [CRUD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD)  БД выбрать по вкусу. Если вкуса нет(шутка), возьмите [postgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Вот такое я когда-то решал... и это я ещё детализировал вам своё задание, у меня было оно ещё менее информативным, приходилось самому принимать решение о выборе архитектуры работы приложений.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно о таких примерах я и говорил!